# generating function for the set of partitions in which no part occurs exactly once (with respect to the size)

Tags: combinatorics

What is the size of a partition?
one can write A as {11, 111, 1111, 11111, ...}{22, 222, 2222, ....}...
If the size of a partition is the length of the string representing a partition then we get by the product lemma that the generating series for A is
$f(x)=(\frac{1}{1-x}-1-x)(\frac{1}{1-x}-1-x)(\frac{1}{1-x}-1-x)(\frac{1}{1-x}-1-x)...$ which is what? $(\frac{1}{1-x}-1-x)$ to the infinity?

Answer (score 0):

$\prod _k^{n} \left(\frac{1}{1-x^k}-x^k\right)$ looks more like it.
See http://oeis.org/A007690 : 0,1,1,2,1,4,2,6,5,9,7,16,11,22,20
If you want to generate each of the partitions counted above, then simply use
$\prod _k^n \left(\frac{1}{1-t_k x^k}-t_k x^k\right)$  which gives (n upto 7)
$0,t_1^2,t_1^3,t_1^4+t_2^2,t_1^5,t_1^6+t_2^2 t_1^2+t_2^3+t_3^2,t_1^7+t_2^2 t_1^3$
with the last term (n=7) to be read as 1111111, 22111.